# PivotTable Assistance

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I currently have data in a .csv file that I need to re-arrange.  It currently looks like this:

```
Parcel    Description  Amount
5099900   ABC          59.00
5099900   DEF          20.00
5099901   ABC          10.00
5099902   DEF           5.00
5099903   ABC           1.00
5099903   DEF          10.00
```

Here is how I need the data displayed:

```
Parcel       Amount    Amount2
5099900      59.00     20.00
5099901      10.00
5099902                5.00
5099903      1.00      10.00
```

I have attempted a pivot table, however it still has the second description on a new line, although it does group them.

Comment: what are you grouping in the pivot table?

Comment: I'm grouping by the parcel so the output looks like:

5099900 ABC 59.00 (then a break)
        DEF 20.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating the PivotTable then copying its body, inserting two columns and adding the Descriptions with formulae in the new columns, say:

in J4:  `=IF(K4="","","ABC")`
in L4:  `=IF(M4="","","DEF")`

copying down and adding headers to suit.

[image: SO18896674 first example]

The PivotTable layout above was based on a Field List as below:

[image: SO18896674 second example]

and in PivotTable Options unchecking the Grand Totals in Totals & Filters and in Field Settings selecting None for Subtotals under Subtotals & Filters.

Comment: Hi pnuts.  How did you get center info (Sum of Amt Row Labels) and Column labels to show up like that?  If I had that I'd be fine but can't get there.

Comment: Ahhh, you'd just updated when I figured out the reason was I had not put the amount in the Sum section.  Thank you very much for your help, my issue has been resolved.